# Как осуществить переключение стилей между элементами JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<p class="yes one">1</p>
<p class="yes two">2</p>
<p class="yes three">3</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

 $('.yes').each(function(){
  if($('.yes').hasClass('active')) $('.yes').removeClass('active');
  $('.yes').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
 })
})
```

```css
p
{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    display: inline-block;
}
.active{
 background-color: #000;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="yes one">1</p>
<p class="yes two">2</p>
<p class="yes three">3</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.yes', function(){
  $('.yes').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
p
{
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    display: inline-block;
}
.active{
 background-color: #000;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="yes one">1</p>
<p class="yes two">2</p>
<p class="yes three">3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function() {
    $('.yes').removeClass('active').filter(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
p{
    font-family:'arial';
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:3px;
}
.active{
 background-color:#000;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="yes one">1</p>
<p class="yes two">2</p>
<p class="yes three">3</p>
```